# SharePoint online - left navigation showing partial list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a GF Navigation term - under that I have terms for different sites - everything shows at the top level pages, but I have subsites that show only a partial even though I have quick launch checked and inherit from parent - I'm not sure what else if anything I need to have checked in order for this to work on all pages.

Can I attached a file to this question?